# Float to Double in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, floating-point, double

I have a column `Probability` of type float in SQL Server whereas I have some calculation in C# as:

```
var _Total_Records = 0;
var _Matchings = 0;
var _Probability = 0.0;

_Matchings = Convert.ToInt32(_myCommand_2.ExecuteScalar());
_Probability = Convert.ToDouble(_Matchings.ToString()) / Convert.ToDouble(_Total_Records);
```

Now I want to write this `_Probability` value into the SQL Server table, while in `WriteToDatabase()` method i.e.

```
public static void Write_To_Database(int _id, int _Matched, double _Prob)
{
     var _Result = 0;
     SqlConnection _con = _cs.GetConnection();
     try
     {
         string _myUpdate_Command_1 = @"UPDATE AuthorCoAuthorProbability 
                                        SET Matched_Records = @_Matched_Records
                                        Probability = @_Probability
                                        WHERE id = @_id";

         SqlCommand _myUpdate_Command = new SqlCommand(_myUpdate_Command_1, _con);
         _myUpdate_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_id", _id);
         _myUpdate_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_Matched_Records", _Matched);
         _myUpdate_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_Probability", _Prob);

         _Result = _myUpdate_Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

         _cs.Dispose();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      }
}
```

at `_Result =_myUpdate_Command.ExecuteNonQuery();` command:

I got the exception i.e.

```
Incorrect syntax near `Probability`
```

Is there any data type fault? As the column data type in SQL Server table is `float` and I'm storing `double` value of `_Probability` in it or due to what else there is the exception?

Comment: You forget to put comma `,` between parameters in your sql query

Comment: `UPDATE AuthorCoAuthorProbability 
                                        SET Matched_Records = @_Matched_Records, 
                                        Probability = @_Probability
                                        WHERE id = @_id`

Comment: It looks like you're just missing a comma to me... surely it should be `SET Matched_Records = @_Matched_Records, Probability = @_Probability`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

there is missing a comma in your SQL Statement

replace

```
SET Matched_Records = @_Matched_Records Probability = @_Probability
```

with

```
SET Matched_Records = @_Matched_Records, Probability = @_Probability
```

Comment: @Byyo--same was suggested by _dotctor_, thanks!